# How to detect touch location of the bottomView when the topView is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, touches

I have four UIViews(topViews) added as subviews to the mainView. I want to create a bezierPath from the topViews to an endposition. For this I need to get the location of the topView with respect to the bottomView.

I want the bottomView not to detect any touches, I only want the topViews to get the touches, but in return give their positions with regards to the bottomView.

How is this possible? I am currently using touchesBegan that is justing giving me location from the whole bottomview.

Comment: you can use `topView.convert(point, to: bottomView)` method to convert point detected from the topView coordinate system to bottomView coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `topView.convert(point, to: bottomView)` method to convert point detected from the topView coordinate system to bottomView coordinate system.